# Creating a pop up window from a drop down box

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to open a drop down menu, and when I select one of the options, a small window will popup with more options available. Something shown in this picture I found: http://datasmugglers.com/wp-content/uploads/mute-someone.jpg

I've googled and searched but I can't find anything close to the solution. I can create a drop down with links that would go to other pages, but thats not what I'm looking for.

Also I'm open to changing languages or using outside libraries like JQuery to accomplish this.

I would post my code but its really just the dropdown tutorial from w3schools with some changes.

Comment: Those changes might be relevant. Show us the code

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

With a default `<select>` control, it can't be done. `OnClickListeners` can't be attached to `<option>` elements.

Backup answer:
You could create a custom dropdownlist, basically creating and styling your own html element and when you click on it, show a list of items i.e. a `<ul>` element with some options and attach onClickListeners to those to show your alerts.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a Modal** - In your HTML document create a modal with `display:hidden`.

**2. Listen For Clicks** - Add an event listener in javascript that will listen for any clicks on your link.

**3. Display your Modal** - When someone clicks on your link, change the display of your modal to be `block`.

```
var link = document.getElementById('your-link');
var modal = document.getElementById('your-modal');

link.addEventListener("click", function(){
   modal.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Long answer:
Here is some example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
    margin-bottom: -250px;
}



/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">popup1
      <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">A Simple Popup1!</span>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">popup2
      <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">A Simple Popup2!</span>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">popup3
      <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup3">A Simple Popup3!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2"); //you can easily switch this with JS
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This example uses `popup.classList.toggle("show");` to show or hide the pop up. You should understand the drop down from w3schools.

Hope this helps!